# Send json data to Kafka producer in Rust

Tags: rust, kafka-producer-api

I have been following Rust kafka producer example, which looks like ..

```
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::time::Duration;
use kafka::producer::{Producer, Record, RequiredAcks};

let mut producer =
    Producer::from_hosts(vec!("localhost:9092".to_owned()))
        .with_ack_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1))
        .with_required_acks(RequiredAcks::One)
        .create()
        .unwrap();

let mut buf = String::with_capacity(2);
for i in 0..10 {
  let _ = write!(&mut buf, "{}", i); // some computation of the message data to be sent
  producer.send(&Record::from_value("my-topic", buf.as_bytes())).unwrap();
  buf.clear();
}
```

This example simply sends numbers from 1 to 10, I can modify this to send strings, but how can I modify this example to send a json, something like ...

```
{
  "cpu": {
     "system": "40",
     "user": "30",
  },
  "ram": 40, 
}
```

Should I create a struct, stringify it & then again objectify at kafka consumer ?
OR does Kafka supports different formats ?

I tried serializing and sending the data as follows ...

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::time::Duration;
use kafka::producer::{Producer, Record, RequiredAcks};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    cpu: f32,
    memory: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut producer =
        Producer::from_hosts(vec!("localhost:29092".to_owned()))
            .with_ack_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1))
            .with_required_acks(RequiredAcks::One)
            .create()
            .unwrap();

            let data = Data{
                cpu: 80.0,
                memory: 40.0,
            };

    let mut buf = String::with_capacity(2);
    for _ in 0..10 {
    // let _ = write!(&mut buf, "{}", i); // some computation of the message data to be sent
    producer.send(&Record::from_value("Users", bincode::serialize(&data).unwrap())).unwrap();
    buf.clear();
    }
}
```

But, at the consumer end (which is written in nodejs), I receive something like this ..

[image]

Comment: Both common Kafka libraries for rust (rdkafka and kafka) don't take care of serialization for you, you need to handle that yourself and hand them [bytes](https://docs.rs/kafka/latest/kafka/producer/trait.AsBytes.html). And well, if you serialize with bincode on the rust side and print that binary on the nodejs side, then the output you are seeing is what you should expect. What did you expect? If you were expecting json, why not try [`serde_json::to_vec`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/fn.to_vec.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Caesar , eventually I tried with serde_json and got the expected format

Comment: What was the topology of your system when running this test example? I attempted to run exactly the same example inside a docker container, on a network where the Kafka instance was also dockerized, and ran into problems. The Rust side panicked. `AddrNotAvailable`.